# how to read data from an open office spread sheet and place it in an array or webpage

Tags: c#

How can i read a set of data from an existing open office calc file and place the values in an array or desired position in web page...my language is csharp...it would be so greatful if any body can help

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=read+excel+data+using+c%23

Usually a good first point of call! GFGI

**Edit**
Same principle applies... i googled, and found:

http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/creating-an-openoffice-calc-document-with-c-a124112.html

I would imagine this helps with your question!

Comment: i am not trying to read excel...my file is open office calc document

Comment: see edit - same principle applies, 30 seconds of effort & you could have found the answer yourself